# Proving that the union of connected sets is connected when consecutive sets have nonempty intersection

Tags: general-topology

Let $\{S_n: n=1,2,\dots\}$ be the collection of connected sets with the property that $S_n\cap S_{n+1} \neq \emptyset$. Prove that $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty S_n$ are connected.

Help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you know that the union of connected sets sharing a point is connected? If so, $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty S_i=\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty\bigcup_{k=1}^i S_k$, so it is enough to prove that $\bigcup_{i=1}^n S_i$ is connected for each $n$, which you can do by induction.

Comment: @user281392 İ have not had that theorem that the union of connected sets sharing a point is connected.

Comment: Let $E$ be a connected component. For each $n$ it either contains $S_n$, or is disjoint from it. But if it contains $S_n$ it must also contain its neighbors $S_{n\pm 1}$. Go from there to conclude $E$ is everything.

Comment: @NormalHuman how do you conclude that it must contain its neightbour $S_{n+1}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $S = \cup_{n=1}^\infty S_n = U \cup V$, where $U$ and $V$ are disjoint and open-and-closed in $S$.

$S_{1}$ is connected, so it cannot be the case that $U$ and $V$ both intersect $S_1$ in a non-empty set. Because if this were the case, $U \cap S_{1}$ and $V \cap S_{1}$ would be a non-trivial disconnection of $S_1$, which cannot be. So say (for definiteness) $S_1 \cap V = \emptyset$, so $S_1 \subseteq U$.

Now we prove by induction that for all $n$, $S_n \subseteq U$ as well.

So we covered the base case $n=1$, and suppose $S_n \subseteq U$.

Now $S_{n+1} \cap S_n \neq \emptyset$, say $p$ is in the intersection. Then $p \in S_n$ so $p \in U$ and so $p \in S_{n+1} \cap U$, by the induction hypothesis. But if $S_{n+1} \cap V \neq \emptyset$, again we conclude that $S_{n+1} \cap U$ and $S_{n+1} \cap V$ are a non-trivial disconnection of $S_{n+1}$ ($p$ is in the left, the other was non-empty by assumption here) which cannot be. So $S_{n+1} \cap V = \emptyset$, so $S_{n+1} \subseteq U$ as well. This completes the induction step.

So $S = \cup_n S_n \subseteq U$ and so $V$ must be empty, showing connectedness of $S$.